# backbone.js bind collection to table

Tags: javascript, json, rest, backbone.js

I got service REST that give me a list in .JSON like this :

```
[{"name":"Temperature","id":32,"description":"Temperature on desk","lastModifier":"admin","lastModification":"2013-07-17"},
{"name":"Presence","id":34,"description":"maDescription2","lastModifier":"admin","lastModification":"2014-01-14"}]
```

And I want to display this list in a table using the 3 attributs name , description and lastModification.

I try these solutions :

http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/9-collection-views-in-backbone-js-learning-backbone-js/#.UwMVDH81jQc

http://liquidmedia.org/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/

But I just don't get it...
This is my code :

**the model :**

```
    var sensors = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "",
        id:"",
        description:"",
        lastModifier:"",
        lastModification:""
    },


});
```

**The collection :**

```
var SensorsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: sensors,
    url:'../../rest/groups'
});
```

**the view:**

```
var SensorsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new sensors(),
    sensorsCollection: new SensorsCollection(),
    el: $("#sensorsDiv"),
    initialize: function(){

    },
    events:{
        "click #btnAddUser": "getSensors"

    },
    getSensors: function(){
        var tokenCookie;

        var name = "xtoken" + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
        {
            var c = ca[i].trim();
            if (c.indexOf(name)==0) tokenCookie = c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
        if(tokenCookie == undefined){
            alert("veuillez vous connecter !")
        }else{

            this.sensorsCollection.fetch({
                headers:{"X-Token":tokenCookie},
                statusCode:{
                    202: function(){

                    }
                }}

            );
        }
    }

});
var sensorsView = new SensorsView();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `el: $("#sensorsDiv"),` by `el: "#sensorsDiv",`

---

Here's an example of how to use template [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yP9AP/)

Comment: The problem is that my sensorsDiv is empty , I don't know how to display my list in a table , the code I wrote is just supposed to fetch the list.

Comment: You can use an underscore template to render the list.

Comment: Thanks but how ? I already seen this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651629/backbone-js-collections-and-views but I don't understand how to do it...(It's the first time I use Backbone.js/javascript)